# Why arent my log messages showing up?

Tags: android, logging, listener

I have some code that build a dialog box and makes a listener for it. The dialog box displays fine, but the code inside the listener doesn't seem to run, and I don't know why.

```
private void showBackgrounDialog() {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MeacruxActivity.this);
        builder.setTitle(R.string.background_dialog_title).setCancelable(true)
                .setItems(R.array.background_options, 
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int selection) {
                                Log.d(logID, "the selection is: " + selection);
                                if(backgrounds.length==selection){
                                    notImplementedYet.show();
                                return;
                            }
                            setBckground(backgrounds[selection]);   
                        }
                    });

    currentDialog = builder.create();
    currentDialog.show();
}

private void setBackground(String bgName) {
        Log.d(logID, bgName);
}
```

The dialog shows up properly with all the options and everything, but when I click on one nothing come sup in the log.... Why is that?

Edit: I did some more testing and I can confirm that the code inside of the `onClick` function is being run, its just that the log isnt showing up...

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you are looking in eclipse or studio
In DDMS view, make sure the device is selected.
In Logcat view, make sure there's not a filter applied.

On terminal, type adb logcat... does it show up there?

Comment: I wasnt in DDMS view, but I did have logcat open, so shouldnt matter. And how do you get to the terminal?

Comment: @vikram In the logcat.

Comment: If your logcat isn't working at the moment(but it usually does), its time to restart eclipse.